# Why Does XLS require "ID#" as first column header when exporting from PHP?

Tags: php, excel, character-encoding

I wrote a utility to export a report from database to xls file. The database had some utf-8 characters which were not being converted into unreadable text when i wrote it to excel. I found a strange solution that if i post the first column first cell as specifically "ID#", it writes perfectly. Rest whatever i do with other columns, doesnt matter. BUT if i put anything else other than ID#, it prints unreadable rows.

For example when I put up ID# in first cell of first row, this is what i get

[image]

which is perfect.

But if i put anything else in the first cell, this is what happens.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
function generate_excel_report($filename, $header_array, $column_names, $data, $attachment_column, $correct_answer_column = FALSE, $insert_correct_answer = False) {
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8");
    iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
    iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "ISO-8859-1");

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($header_array); $i++) {
        echo $header_array[$i] . "\t";
    }
    echo "\n";
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $k = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($header_array); $i++) {
            if ($i == $attachment_column) {
                if ($row['attachment_type'] != '') {
                    echo '"' . $row['attachment_url'] . '"' . "\t";
                } else {
                    echo '"' . $row[$column_names[$k]] . '"' . "\t";
                    $k++;
                }
            } else if ($i == $correct_answer_column && $insert_correct_answer) {
                echo '"' . $row['option_' . $row['correct_answer']] . '"' . "\t";
            } else {
                if ($i == 0) {
                    echo '"' . ++$j . '"' . "\t";
                } else {
                    echo '"' . $row[$column_names[$k]] . '"' . "\t";
                    $k++;
                }
            }
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

I have absolutely no idea why it is doing so...Anyone can help here?

Thanks

Comment: You are not generating an `.xls` file but a [`tab-separated-values`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values). You should produce the correct `Content-Type` header. Then, make the encoding declared in the `Content-Type` header match the actual encoding you use to output the values. Both should be `UTF-8` or other multi-byte character encoding (not `ISO-8859-1`). Finally, if you are sure the output you produce is encoded as `UTF-8` then you can try to output an `UTF-8` [`BOM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) before any other content (`echo("\xEF\xBB\xBF");`)

Comment: ok you may be right but that doesnt work out the logic that why specifically it works for "ID#"?

Comment: Do you open the file using Excel? MS Excel and other MS programs and some components of Windows try hard to detect the encoding of a text fragment when the correct encoding is not known/provided, in order to provide the best experience to the customer. For this purpose they use several hundred bytes from the beginning of the file and (beside other things) they look for some sequences of bytes. It's possible that the sequence `ID#` triggers the correct encoding (or, at least, makes it think your file uses a multi-byte encoding) while the lack of `#` makes it think the encoding is `ISO-8859-1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Excel thinks that Text files starting with IDxxx are in SYLK Format.
See e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYmbolic_LinK_(SYLK))
You can with Id oder 'ID (with apostrophe) but not ID.